# In Python 2.7, How to use scp with variable filename?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following codeline written in python 2.7. I am using centos6 as OS.
Right now I am new to python & trying to learn it.

Following code line copies all specific files (i.e. containing letter "R") in the folder /2013_06_02 from remote machine 192.168.13.152 to my local machine *(tony is my username on my local machine; while john is my username on remote machine)*

```
os.system("scp john@192.168.13.152:/home/john/2013_06_02/11_RBPLJ1635+3808*R* /home/tony/data/")
```

**This works.** (This code line asks password). And I get specific files in my /data directory on my local machine.

**Now the problem part:**
Actually I have many folders on remote machine, each one contains many files with filenames which contain letter "R". Also Each filename begins with some no. like 11 in above example.
Now I want to vary folder name and at the same time vary no. appearing in front of filename.

I tried this:

```
date = "2013_10_05"
mynum = "11"
os.system("scp john@192.168.13.152:/home/john/date/mynum_RBPLJ1635+3808*R* /home/tony/data/")
```

But I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I tried this way also:

```
date = "2013_10_05"
mynum = "11"
os.system("scp john@192.168.13.152:/home/john/"date"/"mynum"_RBPLJ1635+3808*R* /home/tony/data/")
```

But this did not work.

In short I have to make folder name & file no. to be two variables to be used in scp command so that code will automate copying process; i.e. I don't have to change folder name & no. in filename by hand everytime.

I know that every time I have to type password to remote machine, if above code line works. But I don't care for that at this moment. First I want to get above codeline into working condition. Then I want to see how I can do above stuff without typing password everytime.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to pass in variables:

```
date = "2013_10_05"
mynum = "11"
os.system("scp john@192.168.13.152:/home/john/{}/{}_RBPLJ1635+3808*R* /home/tony/data/".format(date,mynum))
```

Using:

`os.system("scp john@192.168.13.152:/home/john/"date"/"mynum"_RBPLJ1635+3808*R* /home/tony/data/")` you have double quotes inside double quotes which is neither valid syntax in python or passing in the variables.

Comment: :I get error for this:   AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: if you have the `.format` outside of the last os.system paren then it won't work. Copy the code exactly

Comment: To Padraic: Yes. It works well. Sorry it was my mistake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use string formatting.

```
date = "2013_10_05"
mynum = "11"
os.system("scp john@192.168.13.152:/home/john/{}/{}_RBPLJ1635+3808*R* /home/tony/data/".format(date, mynum))
```

I recommend that you take a look at [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). It's great for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to run is:

```
date = "2013_10_05"
mynum = "11"
os.system("scp john@192.168.13.152:/home/john/%s/%s_RBPLJ1635+3808*R* /home/tony/data/" %(date, mynum))
```

Comment: I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'tuple'@kvivek

Comment: To Kvivek: It works now. I got my mistake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this `cmdStr = "scp john@192.168.13.152:/home/john/%s/%s_RBPLJ1635+3808*R* /home/tony/data/" %(date, mynum)` working?